# BigBlueButton: Fullscreen Button Not Working in Recorded sessions

Tags: html, next.js, bigbluebutton

I am using BigBlueButton for recording sessions, and I have noticed that the fullscreen button in the recorded sessions does not function in the same way as the fullscreen button in YouTube videos. When I click the fullscreen button in BigBlueButton's recorded sessions, the video does not expand to fill the entire screen.

I have tried using different browsers and devices, but the issue persists. It seems that the fullscreen functionality in BigBlueButton's recorded sessions is not working as expected.

Has anyone encountered this issue before? Is there a known workaround or a fix for this problem? I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this fullscreen button issue in BigBlueButton recorded sessions.

Thank you in advance for your help!

```
<iframe title="Recorded video" 
style={{ marginLeft: '0.6rem', marginRight: '0.6rem', borderRadius: '0.5rem' }}
width={'auto'}
height={'690vh'}
src={url[0] + '?l=content'} //url contains the recorded video of bigbluebutton
allowFullScreen />
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxthc.png)